# How to access data selected using scopes in NextAuth through Github OAuth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm making a project where I'm using Github's OAuth along with NextAuth.js. So like usual I used the Github provider as specified it as below:

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: "read:repo_hook user:email"
        }
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

I can authenticate and sign in as usual. But my question is, how do I actually access the data? Like for example the scope here allows me to access repository names probably. How do I go about fetching them? Can someone please give an example about how I can actually access the data?

I tried using the useSession() hook but got stuck.